# instantiate a django form in readonly mode in a view function

Tags: python, django, django-forms, readonly, django-widget

I have a django 4 form having some widgets for the user to select some values:

```py
from django import forms
from .app.model import MyModel
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets import DatePickerInput

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
   # stuff
    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        fields = [
            "user_id",
            "created_at",
            "some_other_field",
        ]

        widgets = {
            "user_id": forms.NumberInput(),
            "created_at": DatePickerInput(),
            "some_other_field": forms.NumberInput(),
        }
```

I instantiate that form in several functions in the `views.py` file:

```py
my_form_instance = forms.FooForm(
    data=data,
    user=request.user,
)
```

One function `create_or_edit_foo()` for creating a new or editing an existing record. And another function `delete_foo()` to delete a record. In the deletion function (used by a specific endpoint `/foo/12/delete`), I want to display the form but in read-only mode.

How could I achieve that?

I know I can add `attrs={'readonly': True,}` in each of the widget to make it non-editable.
But this will also apply to the form instances used by the create_or_edit function in my views.

I'm using django 4.2 on Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For KISS, you Can use named argument.

```
def delete_foo():
    my_form_instance = formes.fooForm(
        data = data,
        User = request.user,
        delete = True,
    )
```

And in your form :

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        fields = [
            "user_id",
            "created_at",
            "some_other_field",
        ]

        widgets = {             
            "user_id":forms.NumberInput(),
            "created_at": DatePickerInput(),
            "some_other_field": forms.NumberInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, delete=None, **kwargs):
        super(fooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if delete:
            for field_name in self.fields : 
                self.fields[field_name].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

why not subclass your form to create a Delete-specific version

```
class MyDeleteForm(MyForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       # set your read-only attributes here
```

then in your delete view, use `MyDeleteForm`

Comment: This could indeed be an idea, however, my wish was to avoid "duplicating" all my forms for such purpose.